# OpenGL: Rotating cannon about non-centre position?

Tags: opengl, python, rotation, pygame

So I have a "cannon" object (basically a long cylinder) and I want to be able to control its angle. The code I have now is:

```
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(self.position.x,2.5,self.position.z)
    glRotated(self.tube_angle, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glScaled(1.0, 0.5, 1.0)
    glCallList(self.tube.gl_list)
    glPopMatrix()
```

This rotates it around the axis, obviously. I want the bottom to stay in the spot it is (moving object) and just change the angle.

Comment: You can teach yourself :) http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/07/Linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-4

Comment: rotate around point P: (1) translate by -P (2) rotate around origin (3) translate by P (4) Profit!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since `glRotated()` rotates a specified angle around the desired axies (x and z in your example), you'll need to translate your object first. This is important.

> **Note: The rotation center is always considered (0,0,0).**

#### Example: Rotate 20° About Point (0, 5, -10)

```cpp
// Save the current display for other items.
glPushMatrix();

// Translate by the opposite of the desired point of rotation.
glTranslate(0, -5, 10);

// perform the desired rotation.
glRotate(20, 1, 0, 0);

// Put the object back where it was.
glTranslate(0, 5, -10);

// Now, draw the object with proper rotation!
...draw code...

// Finally, reset our transformation matrix to where we left it.
// It's the polite thing to do, after all.
glPopMatrix();
```